# Multiple subscriptions with different subscription rate design through boost::beast

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am trying to design a system where I am creating a tree like structure and users can subscribe to any branch of the tree. Ex: If a tree looks like

```
A--B--C
        |
        D
```

Here A is the parent of B and B is the parent of C and D
Now, a user places a subscription request of 5 seconds on the branch A-B-D.
A 5 seconds subscription request mean that the user who has placed this subscription through a GUI or whatever should get the updates of A,B and D nodes every 5 seconds(the updates for the three nodes should be sent at the same time).

The user on his GUI is essentially looking at a row with A 
( and some metrics corresponding to it )with a child row of B and row B having a child row of D and he wants to see the updates for the three rows at the same time(Kind of a drill down table). 
There can be another user who has subscribed on A-B-C and might have subscribed to this branch with a rate of 10 seconds.

This server code of tree is developed in C++ and I am trying to integrate it to boost::beast for connecting it to HTTP web sockets through which the subscriptions will be made. However, I am wondering if there is a module in boost::beast which will help me maintain these multiple subscriptions at different rates use case.

Answer (score 0):

No. Beast is a low level HTTP/WebSocket protocol library. You are asking for a higher level feature.